# How to dynamically create a Blaze Template from database string

Tags: meteor, viewmodel, meteor-blaze

I'm using Meteor's blaze viewmodel.org, a couple of years back I found a way to save blaze templates and viewmodels in database and render them dynamically, But unforuntatley I lost the code and I could not recreate this as it was not documented anywhere.

How do I recreate the same behavior?

Sample database

```
db.templates.insert({
    name: "templateName",
    blaze: "Hello {{viewmodelNameHelper}}",
    viewmodel: " { onCreated() {console.log('oncreated hook')}, viewmodelNameHelper(){return 'Your Name!'} }"

});
```

viewContainer.html

```
<template name="viewContainer">
 {{ myRenderTemplateHelper  }}
</template>
```

viewContainer.js

```
Template.viewContainer.viewmodel({

  onCreated(){
    // subscribe for template from database
  },
  myRenderTemplateHelper(){
     // required code here
  } 
})
```

Output

```
Hello Your Name!
```

Please note that Template.dynamic and Blaze.renderWithData() won't help as I need to attach the dynamic viewmodel object to the created template instance. where all the viewmodel helpers and events are reactive.

I also tried to do the same using react but I couldn't find enough resources on that?

Comment: I'm thinking of a solution that relies on mixins but I'm facing an issue with converting the string in viewmodel property in DB to code. The solution would be to retrieve your desired template from DB in `onCreated` and then dynamically add a new mixin to `ViewModel.mixin` and push this mixin in your viewmodel `mixins` property.

Comment: It'd look like something like this: 
```
Template.home.viewmodel({
  mixin: ['dynamicTemplate'],
  onCreated() {
    Meteor.subscribe('templates', () => {
      const dbTemplate = blazeTemplates.findOne({});
      ViewModel.mixin({ dynamicTemplate: dbTemplate.viewmodel });
    });
    console.log(this);
  },
  myRenderTemplateHelper() {},
});
```

Comment: All in all, you should be looking into how to do this with viewmodel not Blaze-centric ways

Comment: A little late but you can take a look how it's done with standard templates: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/deprecated/markdown/template-integration.js